# Confusion on cs231n image classification implementation

Tags: python-2.7, deep-learning

I am recently taking CS231n online class. Trying to implement simple image classification code using CIFAR-10 dataset, in http://cs231n.github.io/classification/

While running this code, on predict function, time takes too long, and even didn't completed. I basically copy-and-pasted all codes. 
My desktop has state-of-art machine.

The code is shown below.

## Load function

```
import os;
import cPickle as pickle;
import numpy as np;
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt;

def load_CIFAR_batch(filename):

    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        datadict=pickle.load(f);

        X=datadict['data'];
        Y=datadict['labels'];

        X=X.reshape(10000, 3, 32, 32).transpose(0,2,3,1).astype("float");
        Y=np.array(Y);

        return X, Y;

def load_CIFAR10(ROOT):

    xs=[];
    ys=[];

    for b in range(1,6):
        f=os.path.join(ROOT, "data_batch_%d" % (b, ));
        X, Y=load_CIFAR_batch(f);
        xs.append(X);
        ys.append(Y);

    Xtr=np.concatenate(xs);
    Ytr=np.concatenate(ys);

    del X, Y;

    Xte, Yte=load_CIFAR_batch(os.path.join(ROOT, "test_batch"));

    return Xtr, Ytr, Xte, Yte;

def visualize_CIFAR(X_train, y_train, samples_per_class):
    classes = ['plane', 'car', 'bird', 'cat', 'deer', 'dog', 'frog', 'horse', 'ship', 'truck'];
    num_classes=len(classes);

    for y, cls in enumerate(classes):
        idxs = np.flatnonzero(y_train == y)
        idxs = np.random.choice(idxs, samples_per_class, replace=False)
        for i, idx in enumerate(idxs):
            plt_idx = i * num_classes + y + 1
            plt.subplot(samples_per_class, num_classes, plt_idx)
            plt.imshow(X_train[idx].astype('uint8'))
            plt.axis('off')
            if i == 0:
                plt.title(cls)

    plt.show();
```

## Nearest Neighbor function

```
class NearestNeighbor:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def train(self, X, y):
        """X is N x D where each row is an example. Y is 1-dimension of size N"""
        # the nearest neighbor classifier simply remembers all the training data
        self.Xtr = X
        self.ytr = y

    def predict(self, X):
        """X is N x D where each row is an example we wish to predict label for"""
        num_test = X.shape[0]
        # lets make sure that the output type matches the input type
        Ypred = np.zeros(num_test, dtype = self.ytr.dtype)

        # loop over all test rows
        for i in xrange(num_test):
            # find the nearest training image to the i'th test image
            # using the L1 distance (sum of absolute value differences)
            distances = np.sum(np.abs(self.Xtr - X[i,:]), axis = 1)
            min_index = np.argmin(distances) # get the index with smallest distance
            Ypred[i] = self.ytr[min_index] # predict the label of the nearest example

        return Ypred

Xtr, Ytr, Xte, Yte = load_CIFAR10('/home/tegg/Downloads/cifar-10-batches-py/')
# flatten out all images to be one-dimensional
Xtr_rows = Xtr.reshape(Xtr.shape[0], 32*32*3) # Xtr_rows become 50000 x 3072
Xte_rows = Xte.reshape(Xte.shape[0], 32*32*3) # Xte_rows become 10000 x 3072

nn = NearestNeighbor() # create a Nearest Neighbor classifier class
nn.train(Xtr_rows, Ytr) # train the classifier on the training images and labels
Yte_predict = nn.predict(Xte_rows) # predict labels on the test images
# and now print the classification accuracy, which is the average number
# of examples that are correctly predicted (i.e. label matches)
```

I think the last line is having trouble.

```
Yte_predict = nn.predict(Xte_rows)
```

While running this code using ipython notebook, It is keep running the code, and not showing result (finish compile). Is there any wrong in my code?

Comment: In my opinion it does take a lot of time. How long did you let the code to run?

Comment: More than 8 hours. Should I leave it for more time?

Comment: For CIFAR-10, that's a lot of time. But this method is actually slow. I tried some small training with this tutorial long time back and I found it really slow. I suggest you take a small fraction of the dataset and train. For a quick inference you should not use the complete dataset.

Comment: Ahh thanks. For this test, I could see some part of results, but cannot show actual result, just blank cursor blinking. I will try smaller dataset.